# Paint replacement for MacOS

Tags: macos, applications, drawing

I need an app that does the following:

- Allow me to paste multiple snapshots from clipboard. Also resize and move them.
- Draw arrows, write texts...

Just what paint on windows does.

I've tried Gimp but is terrible slow and full of bugs.

Comment: Are you willing to pay for the replacement?

Comment: Depending on the price. If its less than 10-20€ it's ok. If it costs 50-100€ for sure not.

Comment: For pasting an image and drawing arrows here are some good alternatives: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162479/paint-net-alternative-for-mac-os-x/162483#162483

Comment: I need to paste multiple images on the same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Acorn](https://flyingmeat.com/acorn/)

> Acorn has everything you need in an image editor.

[image: Acorn 6]

See also [Can anyone recommend an app for creating flowcharts and diagrams?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6490) for other suggestions.

Comment: I've pasted an image from clipboard but I can't resize it...

Comment: Look for the **Scale** menu item option. Alternatively, you can move and scale the entire layer the clipboard image is on.

Comment: I've tested it, and it's really amazing! Thanks for the recommendation.